# Multiple JComboboxes for one List

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, combobox

I'm currently facing a problem while having multiple Comboboxes for one List of Strings.

I have 1-5 Comboboxes depending on the selection of another Combobox.
When the User selects "3" then Combobox 4 and 5 become hidden.
At the moment I added the StringLists content to every Combobox at the start of the programm, allowing to select the same element on two different comboboxes.

My goal is to have the Comboboxes remove items that are selected by other visible Comboboxes already / add them back to every other visible Combobox when another Combobox changes the selected item.

Here is a quick example how it should look like in the end:

List has {"Cheese","Bread", "Butter}
The standard amount of comboboxes is 2
Combobox1 has "Cheese" selected and "Butter" as another option
Combobox2 has "Bread" selected and also "Butter" as another option

The user changes selected Item of Combobox2 to "Butter"
Combobox1 has "Cheese" selected and "Bread" as another option
Combobox2 has "Butter" selected and also "Bread" as another option

The user selects 3
Combox1 has "Cheese" selected
Combox2 has "Butter" selected
Combox3 has "Bread" selected

I really dont know how I could do this without having to use multiple switch cases to remove and add the item for every possible outcome. I have looked for other posts on similar problems and found 2 or 3 but they didn't really apply for the visible/invisible comboboxes problem.

Every kind of help is appriciated :)

Comment: I think that code ([mcve] ) would have been clearer and shorter than the attempt to describe it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I think in this case It's easier this way. My code is a mess and I don't know how I could put this example into code. Thats why I'm asking for someone to help me with that in the first place.